# Mutable or Immutable class below?

Tags: oop, groovy

> In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object is
>   an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created. This is
>   in contrast to a mutable object, which can be modified after it is
>   created.

Mutable or Immutable class below? I think it's mutable because static field `singleton` changes after `new MavenPush(project)`, but I need 100% correct answer. It's groovy code, but it's like Java code

```
final class MavenPush {

    private static volatile MavenPush singleton = null

    private final def project

    private MavenPush(project) {
        this.project = project
    }

    static MavenPush with(project) {
        if (singleton == null) {
            synchronized (MavenPush.class) {
                if (singleton == null) {
                    singleton = new MavenPush(project)
                }
            }  
        }
        return singleton
    }
}
```

Comment: what is type of `project`?

Comment: An instance of the class is immutable, the class is mutable as a field of the class gets mutated.

Comment: @ShanuGupta Type of project is Context, for example

Comment: You need "100% correct answer" give the contact info for your teacher and I'll send it to them. No worries.

Comment: @nicomp It's for https://github.com/Vorlonsoft/GradleMavenPush (my company's Open Source project)

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic Could you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of the class is immutable, the class is mutable as a field of the class gets mutated.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* an immutable instance; but also useless - there are no getters (unless groovy does that implicitly - I am not aware if this happens).

Comment: But `singleton` field is `volatile`, there is `if (singleton == null)` in the `synchronized` block and `singleton` can be changed only in `synchronized` block? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

As stated already, the instances of the class *look* immutable (final properties can only be initialized in the c'tor).  But since you left the type out for `project` this really depends on that.  If you pass a `String` you really have something immutable (Java strings are immutable) - if not: this is basically just an immutable reference to something mutable and all your expectiations about that may shatter at some point.

Now for that static member:

From an OO view, singleton seems like the wrong name.  The [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is quite well known, but what you have here, is a "last item changed cache".

From an FP view: `with` is often used in a context, where you want to create a modified version of immutable data.  So if you run `with` from instances you earlier got, you dont "copy and change" from the *instance* but from your "global last item cache (singleton)" - that is no problem with the simple example (just one property), but might be with the "real code".